# Stat and file not modified in last minutes

Tags: stat

I need to get with stat unix command (or similar like find) possibly on one line of command all file in a folder that ARE NOT changed in the last 5 minutes for example.
I found a lot of examples with opposite: search file in a dir modified in last 3 minutes or similar.
What I need is to find files that are NOT changed (using modification time os size in bytes) in last x minutes.

Is possible to do that?

Stefano

Answer (score 1):

find supports the -not operator for any option.

So use the most appropriate find command you've found and put -not in there.

Try this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -mmin -5
```